# what is 'comments' mean in this code

Tags: python, django

```
{% load comments %}
```

where defined 'comments' ,a viewer? or a template??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a template tag library.  For example:

```
{% load cache %}
```

loads the [caching tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching).

Custom tags can be defined and placed within your project structure as defined [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).

Answer (score 1):

It's a template tag that loads a specific set of other template tags (comments application specific tags in this case) making them available in the rest of the template file to use.

So, for example, you will be able to use other comments-app specific tags like:

```
{% get_comment_count for entry as comment_count %}
```

You can obtain more info here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#comment-template-tags

and here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load

To understand how to make a set of custom template tags yourself and how to make them available to use via the same method, look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, `comments` is a templatetag.

To answer your question:

> where defined 'comments'

in `django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py`

Here you go: http://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py

Source:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib import comments
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

register = template.Library()

class BaseCommentNode(template.Node):
    """
    Base helper class (abstract) for handling the get_comment_* template tags.
    Looks a bit strange, but the subclasses below should make this a bit more
    obvious.
    """

    #@classmethod
    def handle_token(cls, parser, token):
    """Class method to parse get_comment_list/count/form and return a Node."""
    tokens = token.contents.split()
    if tokens[1] != 'for':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Second argument in %r tag must be 'for'" % tokens[0])

    # {% get_whatever for obj as varname %}
    if len(tokens) == 5:
        if tokens[3] != 'as':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Third argument in %r must be 'as'" % tokens[0])
        return cls(
        object_expr = parser.compile_filter(tokens[2]),
        as_varname = tokens[4],
        )

    # {% get_whatever for app.model pk as varname %}
    elif len(tokens) == 6:
        if tokens[4] != 'as':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Fourth argument in %r must be 'as'" % tokens[0])
        return cls(
        ctype = BaseCommentNode.lookup_content_type(tokens[2], tokens[0]),
        object_pk_expr = parser.compile_filter(tokens[3]),
        as_varname = tokens[5]
        )

    else:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires 4 or 5 arguments" % tokens[0])

    handle_token = classmethod(handle_token)

    #@staticmethod
    def lookup_content_type(token, tagname):
    try:
        app, model = token.split('.')
        return ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app, model=model)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Third argument in %r must be in the format 'app.model'" % tagname)
    except ContentType.DoesNotExist:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag has non-existant content-type: '%s.%s'" % (tagname, app, model))
    lookup_content_type = staticmethod(lookup_content_type)

    def __init__(self, ctype=None, object_pk_expr=None, object_expr=None, as_varname=None, comment=None):
    if ctype is None and object_expr is None:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Comment nodes must be given either a literal object or a ctype and object pk.")
    self.comment_model = comments.get_model()
    self.as_varname = as_varname
    self.ctype = ctype
    self.object_pk_expr = object_pk_expr
    self.object_expr = object_expr
    self.comment = comment

    def render(self, context):
    qs = self.get_query_set(context)
    context[self.as_varname] = self.get_context_value_from_queryset(context, qs)
    return ''

    def get_query_set(self, context):
    ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
    if not object_pk:
        return self.comment_model.objects.none()

    qs = self.comment_model.objects.filter(
        content_type = ctype,
        object_pk    = smart_unicode(object_pk),
        site__pk     = settings.SITE_ID,
    )

    # The is_public and is_removed fields are implementation details of the
    # built-in comment model's spam filtering system, so they might not
    # be present on a custom comment model subclass. If they exist, we
    # should filter on them.
    field_names = [f.name for f in self.comment_model._meta.fields]
    if 'is_public' in field_names:
        qs = qs.filter(is_public=True)
    if getattr(settings, 'COMMENTS_HIDE_REMOVED', True) and 'is_removed' in field_names:
        qs = qs.filter(is_removed=False)

    return qs

    def get_target_ctype_pk(self, context):
    if self.object_expr:
        try:
        obj = self.object_expr.resolve(context)
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
        return None, None
        return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), obj.pk
    else:
        return self.ctype, self.object_pk_expr.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)

    def get_context_value_from_queryset(self, context, qs):
    """Subclasses should override this."""
    raise NotImplementedError

class CommentListNode(BaseCommentNode):
    """Insert a list of comments into the context."""
    def get_context_value_from_queryset(self, context, qs):
    return list(qs)

class CommentCountNode(BaseCommentNode):
    """Insert a count of comments into the context."""
    def get_context_value_from_queryset(self, context, qs):
    return qs.count()

class CommentFormNode(BaseCommentNode):
    """Insert a form for the comment model into the context."""

    def get_form(self, context):
    ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
    if object_pk:
        return comments.get_form()(ctype.get_object_for_this_type(pk=object_pk))
    else:
        return None

    def render(self, context):
    context[self.as_varname] = self.get_form(context)
    return ''

class RenderCommentFormNode(CommentFormNode):
    """Render the comment form directly"""

    #@classmethod
    def handle_token(cls, parser, token):
    """Class method to parse render_comment_form and return a Node."""
    tokens = token.contents.split()
    if tokens[1] != 'for':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Second argument in %r tag must be 'for'" % tokens[0])

    # {% render_comment_form for obj %}
    if len(tokens) == 3:
        return cls(object_expr=parser.compile_filter(tokens[2]))

    # {% render_comment_form for app.models pk %}
    elif len(tokens) == 4:
        return cls(
        ctype = BaseCommentNode.lookup_content_type(tokens[2], tokens[0]),
        object_pk_expr = parser.compile_filter(tokens[3])
        )
    handle_token = classmethod(handle_token)

    def render(self, context):
    ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
    if object_pk:
        template_search_list = [
        "comments/%s/%s/form.html" % (ctype.app_label, ctype.model),
        "comments/%s/form.html" % ctype.app_label,
        "comments/form.html"
        ]
        context.push()
        formstr = render_to_string(template_search_list, {"form" : self.get_form(context)}, context)
        context.pop()
        return formstr
    else:
        return ''

class RenderCommentListNode(CommentListNode):
    """Render the comment list directly"""

    #@classmethod
    def handle_token(cls, parser, token):
    """Class method to parse render_comment_list and return a Node."""
    tokens = token.contents.split()
    if tokens[1] != 'for':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Second argument in %r tag must be 'for'" % tokens[0])

    # {% render_comment_list for obj %}
    if len(tokens) == 3:
        return cls(object_expr=parser.compile_filter(tokens[2]))

    # {% render_comment_list for app.models pk %}
    elif len(tokens) == 4:
        return cls(
        ctype = BaseCommentNode.lookup_content_type(tokens[2], tokens[0]),
        object_pk_expr = parser.compile_filter(tokens[3])
        )
    handle_token = classmethod(handle_token)

    def render(self, context):
    ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
    if object_pk:
        template_search_list = [
        "comments/%s/%s/list.html" % (ctype.app_label, ctype.model),
        "comments/%s/list.html" % ctype.app_label,
        "comments/list.html"
        ]
        qs = self.get_query_set(context)
        context.push()
        liststr = render_to_string(template_search_list, {
        "comment_list" : self.get_context_value_from_queryset(context, qs)
        }, context)
        context.pop()
        return liststr
    else:
        return ''

# We could just register each classmethod directly, but then we'd lose out on
# the automagic docstrings-into-admin-docs tricks. So each node gets a cute
# wrapper function that just exists to hold the docstring.

#@register.tag
def get_comment_count(parser, token):
    """
    Gets the comment count for the given params and populates the template
    context with a variable containing that value, whose name is defined by the
    'as' clause.

    Syntax::

    {% get_comment_count for [object] as [varname]  %}
    {% get_comment_count for [app].[model] [object_id] as [varname]  %}

    Example usage::

    {% get_comment_count for event as comment_count %}
    {% get_comment_count for calendar.event event.id as comment_count %}
    {% get_comment_count for calendar.event 17 as comment_count %}

    """
    return CommentCountNode.handle_token(parser, token)

#@register.tag
def get_comment_list(parser, token):
    """
    Gets the list of comments for the given params and populates the template
    context with a variable containing that value, whose name is defined by the
    'as' clause.

    Syntax::

    {% get_comment_list for [object] as [varname]  %}
    {% get_comment_list for [app].[model] [object_id] as [varname]  %}

    Example usage::

    {% get_comment_list for event as comment_list %}
    {% for comment in comment_list %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}

    """
    return CommentListNode.handle_token(parser, token)

#@register.tag
def render_comment_list(parser, token):
    """
    Render the comment list (as returned by ``{% get_comment_list %}``)
    through the ``comments/list.html`` template

    Syntax::

    {% render_comment_list for [object] %}
    {% render_comment_list for [app].[model] [object_id] %}

    Example usage::

    {% render_comment_list for event %}

    """
    return RenderCommentListNode.handle_token(parser, token)

#@register.tag
def get_comment_form(parser, token):
    """
    Get a (new) form object to post a new comment.

    Syntax::

    {% get_comment_form for [object] as [varname] %}
    {% get_comment_form for [app].[model] [object_id] as [varname] %}
    """
    return CommentFormNode.handle_token(parser, token)

#@register.tag
def render_comment_form(parser, token):
    """
    Render the comment form (as returned by ``{% render_comment_form %}``) through
    the ``comments/form.html`` template.

    Syntax::

    {% render_comment_form for [object] %}
    {% render_comment_form for [app].[model] [object_id] %}
    """
    return RenderCommentFormNode.handle_token(parser, token)

#@register.simple_tag
def comment_form_target():
    """
    Get the target URL for the comment form.

    Example::

    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
    """
    return comments.get_form_target()

#@register.simple_tag
def get_comment_permalink(comment, anchor_pattern=None):
    """
    Get the permalink for a comment, optionally specifying the format of the
    named anchor to be appended to the end of the URL.

    Example::
    {{ get_comment_permalink comment "#c%(id)s-by-%(user_name)s" }}
    """

    if anchor_pattern:
    return comment.get_absolute_url(anchor_pattern)
    return comment.get_absolute_url()

register.tag(get_comment_count)
register.tag(get_comment_list)
register.tag(get_comment_form)
register.tag(render_comment_form)
register.simple_tag(comment_form_target)
register.simple_tag(get_comment_permalink)
register.tag(render_comment_list)
```